# Unable to Load Tab-delimited Txt File from S3 into Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

At SQLWorkbenchJ, I am trying to load a text file that is 'tab' delimited from Amazon S3 into Redshift by using this command:

```
COPY table_property
FROM 's3://...txt’
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=…;aws_secret_access_key=…’
IGNOREHEADER 1
DELIMITER '\t';
```

But it returns the following warning:

```
Warnings:
Load into table 'table_property' completed, 0 record(s) loaded successfully.
```

I have checked various Stackoverflow sources and [Tutorial: Loading Data from Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-loading-run-copy.html) but neither of the solutions works.

My data from the text file looks like this:

```
BLDGSQFT    DESCRIPTION LANDVAL STRUCVAL    LOTAREA OWNER_PERCENTAGE
12440   Apartment 15 Units or more      2013005 1342004 1716    100
20247   Apartment 15 Units or more      8649930 5766620 7796.25 100
101             
1635    Live/Work Condominium                   977685  651790  0   100
```

Does anyone have the solution to this?

Comment: Could you please share a few lines of your data file, also as mentioned by @John Rotenstein, you can check stl_load_errors using 'select * from stl_load_errors order by starttime desc limit 1'  query.

Comment: Hi @AjGupta, I have share a few lines of my data file. I tried using stl_load_errors and it didn't return any content.

Answer (score 1):

Check the table [STL_LOAD_ERRORS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html) and [STL_LOADERROR_DETAIL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOADERROR_DETAIL.html) for the precise error message.

Comment: Hello. So I tried running both STL_LOAD_ERRORS and STL_LOADERROR_DETAIL, but it returns only the column headers (ie. userid, slice, tbl, starttime, ..., err_reason) with no content.

Answer (score 0):

The message you are talking about is not an "Error". Your table will have all records. It just say there was no addition records added.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `DELIMITER '\\t'` instead of `DELIMITER '\t'`. That worked in many of my cases working with Redshift from Java, PHP, and Python. Or sometimes even more '\' signs. It's tied to how IDEs/languages interpret string queries that are supposed to be executed.

For example, this is my code from Airflow DAG, something I'm working on right now (doesn't matter if you are not familiar with Airflow, it's basically Python code.

```
redshift_load_task = PostgresOperator(task_id='s3_to_redshift',
    sql=" \
    COPY " + table_name + "  \
    FROM '{{ params.source }}'  \
    ACCESS_KEY_ID '{{ params.access_key}}'  \
    SECRET_ACCESS_KEY '{{ params.secret_key }}'  \
    REGION 'us-west-2'  \
    ACCEPTINVCHARS  \
    IGNOREHEADER 1  \
    FILLRECORD  \
    DELIMITER '\\t' \
    BLANKSASNULL  \
    EMPTYASNULL  \
    MAXERROR 100  \
    DATEFORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD' \
    ",
    postgres_conn_id="de_redshift",
    database="my_database",
    params={
        'source': 's3://' + s3_bucket_name + '/' + s3_bucket_key + '/' + filename,
        'access_key': s3.get_credentials().access_key,
        'secret_key': s3.get_credentials().secret_key,
    },
)
```

Notice how I defined the delimiter `DELIMITER '\\t'` instead of `DELIMITER '\t'`.
Another example is part of Hive query, executed via Java code on Spark:

```
...
AND (ip_address RLIKE \"^\\\\d+\\\\.\\\\d+\\\\.\\\\d+\\\\.\\\\d+$\")"
...
```

Notice here how there are 4 backslashes in order to escape d in the regex, instead of only writing `\d`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the change? That looks pretty like the same to me?

Comment: I edited the comment. Didn't notice that the editor removed one backslash. The idea is: instead of \t, type \\t. That has an effect because of the escaping of the characters, the same as it did in my answer because I wrote two backslashes t and one backslash t, and it only displayed one backslash t both times.